# How to get out of "sudo -s" command in Terminal?

Tags: command-line, sudo

I entered `sudo -s` command in terminal, and the it changed from

```
shameek@shameek-K55VD:~$
```

to

```
root@shameek-K55VD:~#.
```

Now when I click on the close terminal window icon it says, "There is still a process running in the terminal, closing it may kill it".

[image: Close this terminal? dialog box]

I am entirely new to Ubuntu, please suggest a command to get back from

```
root@shameek-K55VD:~#
```

to

```
shameek@shameek-K55VD:~$
```

and then I can close the terminal.

Comment: If you are sure that you've finished whatever you was doing in terminal, just close by killing the [possible] process...

Comment: By using "exit" or Ctrl-D, you will be warned if there are any background processes which need a terminal.  Forcibly closing the terminal may cause work to be lost otherwise.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> will log you out of Super User and return you to normal user status. Alternatively, you can type `exit`

Comment: With 1 slight cave-at: if $IGNOREEOF is active control-d is not useable.

Comment: To add an explanation of what is happening: `sudo -s` really just starts a new shell as the *root* user as a subprocess, rather than changing the credentials of the existing shell. To the Terminal, this is indistinguishable from any other command that is still running. You exit the inner shell just as you would exit any other. This also means that shells are stackable -- you can just invoke `bash` and get a new shell inside the old one.

Comment: Also, if you haven't reset it, the SHLVL environment variable will tell you how many layers of shell you have running.

Answer (score 35):

Type `exit` then you will log off to normal user. Then type `exit` again to close the terminal or just close it with the mouse.

[image: GNOME Terminal showing exit command to escape from a subshell]

Comment: @EliahKagan what exactly is the difference between `sudo su` and `sudo -s`?

Comment: sudo -s will not run shell environment which is specified in passwd file. But it will not change some environment variables ex: $HOME

Answer (score 13):

If you're not doing anything important in the terminal, you can actually just click **Close Terminal** on the *Close this terminal?* ("Closing the terminal will kill it") dialog box.

This will send [`SIGHUP`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIGHUP#SIGHUP) to the running shell, which will then quit, just like it would if you used [the `exit` command](https://askubuntu.com/a/342037/22949) or [<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>](https://askubuntu.com/a/342036/22949) (also good ways).